# R Caret's timeslices - window and horizon unclear

Tags: r, time-series, r-caret

Using the timeslicing in caret, and it's parameters,
how do I split up data with xyz rows with each having a length of 12?

Ideally, also considering the 60-20-20 train-test-validate ratio.

Should I set it like so:

initialWindow=12, horizon=12, fixedWindow=TRUE?

I've read the documentation but this is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try out what happens using an example vector like `1:100`. 
If you set `window = 12` and `fixedWindow = T` the training sets will always have 12 rows. `horizon` specifies the size of the subsequent observations that will be included in the test sets. If it is set to 12 and you do not want any rows to be predicted multiple times `skip` has to be set to (horizon - 1).

A partitioning of 60-20-20 can be achieved for example by setting `initialWindow` to the size of the first 60% and first running your model on the first half of `slices` and using the second half of `slices` as the last 20%.

I don't know if you are trying to use timeslicing inside of caret's `train` function already. In any case, you can experiment with the different settings using the `createTimeSlices()` function:

```
library(caret)
dat <- 1:100

slices <- createTimeSlices(dat, initialWindow = 12, horizon = 1, 
                           skip = 0, fixedWindow = T)
slices # 88 test and train sets
# [...]

slices <- createTimeSlices(y = dat, initialWindow = 12, horizon = 12,
                           skip = 11, fixedWindow = T)
slices 
# 7 test and train sets, observations 97 - 100 not in any test set

$train
$train$Training01
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

$train$Training13
 [1] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24

$train$Training25
 [1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36

$train$Training37
 [1] 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48

$train$Training49
 [1] 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60

$train$Training61
 [1] 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72

$train$Training73
 [1] 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84


$test
$test$Testing01
 [1] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24

$test$Testing13
 [1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36

$test$Testing25
 [1] 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48

$test$Testing37
 [1] 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60

$test$Testing49
 [1] 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72

$test$Testing61
 [1] 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84

$test$Testing73
 [1] 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96
```

Answer (score 0):

**Initial window + horizon - 1** will ensure your training folds and testing folds do not overlap.

```
timeSlices <- createTimeSlices(1:nrow(DF), initialWindow = 36, horizon = 6, skip = 41, fixedWindow = TRUE)
trainSlices <- timeSlices[[1]]
testSlices <- timeSlices[[2]]
testSlices <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, testSlices)
trainSlices <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, trainSlices)
```